# Adobe Dreamweaver: Apply Source Formatting hotkey

Tags: format, adobe, dreamweaver

I am using Adobe Dreamweaver, and I am using an **Apply Source Formatting** feature. But how can I perform this with a hotkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the main menu, select `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts`. In that dialog, expand the `Commands` tree, there you will find `Apply Source Formatting` and can assign a hotkey.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for.